# Java Bukkit API Test for item name

Tags: java, api, minecraft, bukkit

I want to test if an item a player is holding has a certain name. If it does then I want it to do the following:

```
Egg egg = player.getWorld().spawn(player.getEyeLocation(), Egg.class);
            egg.setVelocity(player.getLocation().getDirection().multiply(1.5));
            egg.setShooter(player);

            player.getWorld().playSound(player.getLocation(), Sound.DIG_WOOL, 15, 15);
```

If it doesn't it should return something say like "Wrong Name!"

Answer (score 1):

Bukkit has a method called [`getItemInHand()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/inventory/PlayerInventory.html#getItemInHand()) on a [`PlayerInventory`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/inventory/PlayerInventory.html) that you can use to get the item in hand. To get a `PlayerInventory`, you can call [`getInventory`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/HumanEntity.html#getInventory()) on a `Player` object.

You can then do checks on the returned object, like checking if it is null, and checking its type:

```
ItemStack item = player.getInventory().getItemInHand();
if(item != null && item.getType() == Material.EGG) {
    if(item.hasItemMeta() && 
       item.getItemMeta().hasDisplayName() && 
       item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals("PartyEgg")) {
        ....
    }
}
```